# Problema de Insert: String sql esta correta, mas não insere pelo Java, só de forma manual pelo Mysql! Procedures atributos data hora

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert

Boa noite pessoal! Estou usando java e Mysql. No momento  estou utilizando de Procedure para inserção tudo ocorre de forma perfeita a String vai para o banco com todos os parâmetros corretos, mas algo ocorre que ela bate no banco, queima o id e não insere os valores no banco, percebi isso após umas tentativas inserindo através do método pelo java, então fiz o debug peguei String que é enviado ao banco testei ela de forma manual no workbench e mesma inseriu normalmente onde percebi que Mysql pulou alguns Ids.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês! :)
Método DAO

```
  public boolean cadastrarTurma(TurmmaBean turma,LoginBean login){
           String sql ="{call inserir_turma(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

       try {

            CallableStatement ps1 = null; 
                ps1 = con.prepareCall(sql);
                ps1.setString(1,login.getNome_user());
                ps1.setString(2,login.getSenha());
                ps1.setString(3, turma.getTur_nome());
                ps1.setString(4, turma.getTur_diciplina());
                ps1.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(turma.getTur_ini_dia().getTime()));
                ps1.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date( turma.getTur_fim_dia().getTime()));
                ps1.setTime(7,new java.sql.Time (turma.getTur_hora_fim().getTime()));
                ps1.setTime(8,new java.sql.Time(turma.getTur_hora_fim().getTime()));
                ps1.setString(9, turma.getTur_dia_semana());
                // Print abaixo para ver o q estava sendo enviado ao banco no momento do teste unitario
                System.out.println(ps1);
                 // Formato da String do ps1 que foi enviada ao banco.
                //call inserir_turma('luis','12345','mateatica quarta','geometria','2018-10-10','2018-10-10','12:00:00','01:00:00','segunda-feira',4);

                ps1.executeUpdate();
                ps1.close();           


                con.close();
                 return true;

            } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Falha ao inserir os dados !");
                //throw new RuntimeException("Erro 1_D   " + e);            
            }
          return false;


    }
```

---

Este é meu teste unitário feito com Junit  onde o mesmo diz que passou não da erro, mas verifico no banco e  nenhum valor está inserido.

```
 @Test
    public void testinserirTurma() throws ParseException {
        TurmmaBean tb =  new TurmmaBean();
            LoginBean lgb = new LoginBean();
            Turma tur = new Turma();
// inicio conversão dos campos de datas  e dos campos de hora nos formatos para o banco
            String   tur_ini_dia = "12/12/1989";
            SimpleDateFormat frm1 = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
               Date c_tur_ini_dia  =  new  SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(tur_ini_dia);
               String dtcnv1 = frm1.format(c_tur_ini_dia);
               c_tur_ini_dia =  frm1.parse(dtcnv1);        


                String tur_fim_dia = "12/12/1989";
                SimpleDateFormat frm2 = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date c_tur_fim_dia =   new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(tur_fim_dia);
                String dtcnv2 = frm2.format(c_tur_fim_dia);
                c_tur_fim_dia =  frm2.parse(dtcnv2);


                String tur_hora_inicio ="12:12";
                java.util.Date c_tur_hora_inicio =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(tur_hora_inicio);
        Time hrCon_ini = new Time(c_tur_hora_inicio.getTime()); 

                String tur_hora_fim ="12:12";
        java.util.Date c_tur_hora_fim =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(tur_hora_fim);
        Time  hrCon_fim = new Time(c_tur_hora_fim.getTime());

                // fim conversão dos campos de datas  e dos campos de hora nos formatos para o banco

//enviado valores convertidos para o DAO
                lgb.setNome_user("luis");
                lgb.setSenha("12345");
                tb.setTur_nome("TESTE2");
                tb.setTur_diciplina("TESTE2");
                tb.setTur_ini_dia (c_tur_ini_dia);
                tb.setTur_fim_dia(c_tur_fim_dia);
                tb.setTur_hora_inicio(hrCon_ini);
                tb.setTur_hora_fim (hrCon_fim);
                tb.setTur_dia_semana("Segunda");

               if( tur.cadastrarTurma(tb ,lgb)){
                   System.out.println("Salvo com sucesso!!!");
               }else{
                   fail("erro ao inserir!!!");

               }
```

Minha procedure recebo dois parâmetro adicionais de login e senha onde ela faz um select e devolve um id que se torna uma fk na outra tabela.

```
##procedure inserir turma

 delimiter $$
create procedure inserir_turma(
in p_log_nome varchar(15), 
in p_log_senha varchar(15),
in p_tur_nome varchar(50) ,
in P_tur_diciplina varchar(50) ,
in P_tur_inicio date ,
in P_tur_fim date ,
in p_tur_hora_inicio time  ,
in p_tur_hora_fim time ,
in P_tur_dia_semana  varchar(20)
)
begin
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT "sem mensagem";
DECLARE excecao SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
declare p_tur_fk_perfil_pro1 int(9);
START TRANSACTION;
select  log_login_id into p_tur_fk_perfil_pro1  from login where log_nome= p_log_nome and log_senha  =p_log_senha; 
insert into turma(
tur_nome, 
tur_diciplina, 
tur_inicio, 
tur_fim, 
tur_hora_inicio, 
tur_hora_fim, 
tur_dia_semana,
tur_fk_perfil_pro  
) 
values(
p_tur_nome, 
P_tur_diciplina, 
P_tur_inicio, 
P_tur_fim, 
p_tur_hora_inicio, 
p_tur_hora_fim,
P_tur_dia_semana,
p_tur_fk_perfil_pro1  
);
end$$
```

Comment: Luiz, talvez seja melhor você editar sua pergunta e colar nela os códigos em formato texto, em vez dessas imagens. Isso por 2 motivos: 1) facilita a leitura de quem for te ajudar; 2) se os links dessas imagens expirarem, sua pergunta ficará sem nenhum sentido.

Comment: Colocar código em imagens é ruim por vários motivos, todos explicados [**no FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto, veja na [**central de ajuda**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) como formatá-lo corretamente. E tente montar o código de forma que os outros possam testar e reproduzir o problema, com exemplos de entrada e saída (o que deveria acontecer x o que aconteceu) e texto das mensagens de erro, caso ocorram. Em outras palavras, tente fazer um **[mcve]**.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, já editei espero que esteja melhor, desculpem pela demora na edição da mesma.

Comment: Pessoal consegui resolver pesquisei por mais de uma semana ai vim até aqui, hoje lendo sobre COMMIT em  procedures, era só isso que me faltava um commit no final da procedure . vocês acham que devo modificar a pergunta para ficar com um melhor entendimento para pessoas com o mesmo problema ? mas muito obrigado pessoal :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O código java estava correto, o erro era na proceure faltava o COMMIT  no final dela !!!!

```
 delimiter $$
create  procedure inserir_turma(
in p_log_nome varchar(15), 
in p_log_senha varchar(15),
in p_tur_nome varchar(50) ,
in P_tur_diciplina varchar(50) ,
in P_tur_inicio date ,
in P_tur_fim date ,
in p_tur_hora_inicio time  ,
in p_tur_hora_fim time ,
in P_tur_dia_semana  varchar(20)
)
begin
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT "sem mensagem";
DECLARE excecao SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
declare p_tur_fk_perfil_pro1 int(9);
START TRANSACTION;
select  log_login_id into p_tur_fk_perfil_pro1  from login where log_nome= p_log_nome and log_senha  =p_log_senha; 
insert into turma(
tur_nome, 
tur_diciplina, 
tur_inicio, 
tur_fim, 
tur_hora_inicio, 
tur_hora_fim, 
tur_dia_semana,
tur_fk_perfil_pro  
) 
values(
p_tur_nome, 
P_tur_diciplina, 
P_tur_inicio, 
P_tur_fim, 
p_tur_hora_inicio, 
p_tur_hora_fim,
P_tur_dia_semana,
p_tur_fk_perfil_pro1 
);

IF excecao = 1 THEN

      ROLLBACK;

   ELSE

      COMMIT; ## <-- resolvido 
   END IF;
end$$
```

Comment: Este codigo é a solução da sua duvida?